# Parent has_many children, find parents containing child

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`Postadmins.where(users: current_user)`

This isn't going to work, but it shows what I'm looking for. A post admin has many users, but I'm looking for all postadmins that 'contains' or 'includes' at least the one particular user.

Comment: Could you please be more specific in 'This isn't going to work'? it not works but shows what you need - how?

Comment: users rather than user. The post admin model contains has_many users. But I'm looking for postadmins that include at least this particular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join users table, try this:

```
Postadmin.joins(:users).where(users: { id: current_user.id } )
```